# Javascript - Create dropdown with preset selected option

Tags: javascript, dropdown, selected

I'm using the following code to create a new dropdown list. The name is used by several dropdowns on the page.

```
  var cellSel = row.insertCell(1);
  var sel1 = document.createElement('select');
  sel1.name = 'list[]';
  sel1.options[0] = new Option('1', '1');
  sel1.options[1] = new Option('2', '2');
  sel1.options[2] = new Option('3', '3');
  sel1.options[3] = new Option('4', '4');
  cellSel.appendChild(sel1);
```

When this has been created I want option 3 to be set as the selected entry, how do I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

Comment: Thanks the document helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cellSel = row.insertCell(1);
var sel1 = document.createElement('select');
sel1.name = 'list[]';
sel1.options[0] = new Option('1', '1');
sel1.options[1] = new Option('2', '2');
sel1.options[2] = new Option('3', '3', true);
sel1.options[3] = new Option('4', '4');
cellSel.appendChild(sel1);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped I needed to set it as `sel1.options[2] = new Option('3', '3', true, true);` to work.

Answer (score -1):

`sel1.options[3].selected = true`

Comment: Post the correspondending html too.